# Is there a Netbeans ruler

Tags: netbeans, ide

Heres a quick questions for all you folks out there:

Is it possible in the Netbeans IDE to show a ruler on top of the coding window - like in Microsoft Word or the Context code editor? If so, how?

I have tried googling it, but to no avail...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am fairly certain that the answer is no, as the editor stands right now. The only thing remotely related is the right-margin line, which can be set in Options, under Editor, then Formatting. It, by no means, serves as a ruler, but at least gives you a hint that you've reached a particular column.

In order to get this functionality, either a module would have to be written that adds the functionality to the editor, or the development team would have to add it to the core editor code. A feature request can be made on [Netbeans.org's issues page](http://netbeans.org/community/issues.html). Be sure to search first, as someone may have already made the request.

Answer (score 0):

If by ruler you mean you want to show which character/column you're on, you can get that information from the looking in the bottom right hand portion of the editor window (shown as "row | column"), but if by ruler you mean grid, it isn't doable with Netbeans out of the box.  You only get the character limit line, which is still defaulted to 80 characters for those required to print their code for review or delivery artifacts (...shiver...)  That limit line can be set in NB 7.2 (et al) from menu Tools -> Options -> Editor -> Formatting then look for Right Margin.  The color can be set on the Tools -> Options -> Fonts and Colors then look for Text Line Limit.

I don't add this next possibility without a bit of eye rolling, but given Netbeans' great horizontal splitting, you could always mimic a top ruler by creating a ruler.txt file with this as the text:

```
***|***1***|***2***|***3***|***4***|***5***|***6***|***7***|***8***|***9***|***0
```

and then grab that file's tab and move it to the top split.  I'll say this now so as to save all those who are at this very moment reaching for their mouse to click on the comment link to blast me, but this is totally hokey and really unnecessary for practical purposes : )